# String Array Returns Null Values

Tags: java

In the following code I read text file with a list of movies and create a String array of the list of movies using a helper method. Within the method I am able to read and print each line of the file. However, when I attempt to iterate over the returned array in the main method I get only "null". Why is this happening. In my research so far, I have not been able to find a similar problem posted by someone else. Please help. Thanks.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class GuessTheMovie {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try {
            // Create File and Scanner objects
            File file = new File("movies.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

            // Create String array to store all movie titles
            List<String> movies = createMoviesArray(scanner);
            for (String movie : movies) {
                System.out.println(movie);
        }
            /*
            String[] movies = createMoviesArray(scanner);
            for (int i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(movies[i]);
            } */

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Could not find file.");
    }

}

////////////////////////// HELPER METHODS ////////////////////////////////////
/*
// Create String array to store all movie titles
private static String[] createMoviesArray(Scanner scanner) {
    int count = 0;
    String[] movies; // = new String[500];
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(count + " : " + line);
        count += 1;
    }
    movies = new String[count];
    return movies;
}*/

private static List<String> createMoviesArray(Scanner scanner) {
    List<String> movies = new ArrayList<>();
    // get line count for the size of the array
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        movies.add(scanner.nextLine());
    }
    return movies;
}
```

Comment: you are not storing the movie titles in your array. You just create the array without populating it.

Comment: You've edited the code in the question to include the code from the accepted answer. This means that anyone reading this question in future might not see it's been edited, and may be confused as to why it was asked in the first place, as the problem can't be replicated with the code provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is quite normal, since you don't put any values in your array.

```
private static String[] createMoviesArray(Scanner scanner) {
    int count = 0;
    String[] movies; // = new String[500];
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(count + " : " + line);
        count += 1;
    }
    movies = new String[count]; // all you do here, is create an array with 'count' spaces, all default values (being null)
    return movies;
}
```

If you want to work like this, you have two options (that immediately jump to mind):

1. Use an array, and create a new one for after every read. This is very resource consuming, meaning: DON'T DO THIS
2. Since you don't know the number of elements before all are read: use a List.

   ```
   private static List<String> createMoviesArray(Scanner scanner) {
       List<String> movies = new ArrayList<>();
       while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
           movies.add(scanner.nextLine());
       }
       return movies;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks Stultuske. I commented out the none working code and updated my post with the new working code. It worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just before `return` in the `createMoviesArray()` method you create a new array. You never add anything to that array and thus it is empty after returning from that method. You should make a new array before iterating over the file.

If you don't know the size of the file and how many lines it has you probably should use some `Collection` with dynamic size, like `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

With your line `movies = new String[count];` you are creating a new array of Strings. At this point in time the array will contain only `NULL` values which. Nowhere in your code you are actually writing something into the array. Thats why your main method correctly prints `null`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not adding the data to the movies array, you are only initializing it.

If you were to print the movies object at the end of your helper method you would see that it also is null.

I suggest using an `ArrayList` as you don't know how large the array needs to be, it would then go something like this:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class GuessTheMovie {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try {
            // Create File and Scanner objects
            File file = new File("movies.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

            // Create String array to store all movie titles
            ArrayList<String> movies = createMoviesArray(scanner); // change this to ArrayList
            for (movie : movies) { // I used a foreach loop
                System.out.println(movie);
            }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Could not find file.");
    }

}

////////////////////////// HELPER METHODS ////////////////////////////////////

// Create String array to store all movie titles
private static String[] createMoviesArray(Scanner scanner) {
    int count = 0;
    ArrayList<String> movies = new ArrayList<String>(); // change to Array List
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(count + " : " + line);
        count += 1;
        movies.add(line); // Add to end of ArrayList
    }
    return movies;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can do the same thing in this way also:-

```
package com.adddemo;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessTheMovie {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    try {
        // Create File and Scanner objects
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\movies.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        // Create String array to store all movie titles
        List movies = createMoviesArray(scanner);
        for (int i = 0; i < movies.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i+" : "+movies.get(i));
        }

 } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Could not find file.");
 }

 }

 ////////////////////////// HELPER METHODS ////////////////////////////////////

// Create String array to store all movie titles
private static List createMoviesArray(Scanner scanner) {
int count = 0;
List movies = new ArrayList<>();
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(count + " : " + line);
    count += 1;
    movies.add(line);
}
return movies;
}
}
```